# VS 2010 debugger not loading symbols when attaching to NUnit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

(I just posted this in the NUnit discussion group on groups.google.com)

Under VS 2008, I would run my tests under NUnit, and, if I needed to
debug, I would attach the VS2008 debugger to the running Nunit process
(Debug -> Attach to Process), and set any breakpoints on code I wanted
to examine. When I hit the Run buttion in NUnit, it would hit the
breakpoint. (BTW, if it matters, this was running NUnit 2.5.2).

I just upgraded to NUnit 2.5.4 and VS 2010.  When I set a breakpoint,
then attach to NUnit, I get a little warning symbol on the breakpoint
dot, and hovering over it gives the tooltip "Breakpoint will not be
hit. No symbols are currently loaded".  Going to the Debug -> Windows -> Modules window shows a whole bunch of Windows and NUnit modules
loaded, with the Symbol Status of "Skipped loading symbols", and then
1 module with a funny name that changes each time (r1euhmh5 right
now), and Symbol Status of "No symbols loaded". (There is no trace of a module with a name remotely like my DLL under test).

Right clicking the funny filename (assuming that to be some mapping from my
DLL under test), and clicking Load Symbols From -> Symbol Path, and
navigating to the bin\debug folder, then clicking the pdb file of my
DLL under test, I get the message "A matching symbol was not found in
this folder".  (The top of the Open dialog box has a line that says
"Original location: r1euhmh5.pdb")

So what's changed?  And how do I go about debugging/breakpointing
under VS 2010/NUnit 2.5.4  (Or is it possible I screwed something up
when I decided to go through my VS2010 options and set some of them to
more advanced levels than I knew what I was doing?)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: +10, OMG! This was driving me nuts for 2 days...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly why, but the answer is to attach the debugger to nunit-agent.exe instead of nunit.exe.  See Charlie Poole's response [here](http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5680d7def5b6982f)

Answer (score 5):

There's information on this [blog post](http://frater.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/debugging-nunit-tests-under-visual-studio-2010/) about how to tell NUnit to use the correct .Net framework in the nunit.exe configuration file.

The benefit to fixing this in the configuration file is that it allows you to set up your unit test project so that you can launch NUnit as an external command when you select Debug -> Start New Instance.