# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, iis-6

I am dealing with a puzzling situation here,and need any help I can get . I am using Visual Studio 2008 and have a dev site running on IIS. When I  Attach to the process running in IIS, it attaches successfully(no errors). However when I attempt to debug, nothing happens. I have closed out my browser, done a restart on the application pool, and website, cleared cache, and even forced a rebuild in visual studio. Still I am unable to step into code. Any idea what I could have wrong here?

**The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.**

Comment: Where have you set your breakpoint?

Comment: Are your breakpoints solid red dots or an outline? Does it give a message when you hover over the breakpoints? ("No symbols have been loaded...")

Comment: Ok . . .  no, I do see the message in bold when I hover over the breakpoints

Comment: I also faced such error and try many solutions but below solution works for me best : its due to different framework version when you try to attach process. For more details, please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13106908/1218422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symbols might be wrong or missing. In extra rare circumstances you might need to step inside the function via assembly, only then VS picks up that you're actually calling your component.

Comment: Also, check in modules window that the module you want to debug has symbols loaded.

Comment: I notice the pop up message " . . .No symbols have been loaded for this document." when I hover over the break point. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have you set  `compilation debug=”true”`  in you web.config file?

Comment: Also check if deployment element <deployment retail="false" /> in your machine.config is set to false. The value if set to true, disables debugging and certain other settings. [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228298%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I just searched the machine.config, and their is no deployment element in there. How do I go about adding one of these and is it safe?

Comment: Also, yes, my web.config compilation debug is set to true

Comment: @Kobojunkie, this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228298%28VS.80%29.aspx) explains how to add deployment element in machine.config. Regarding safety, you should revert it back after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to debug the website from within Visual Studio in order for breakpoints to be hit.  Use the green "play" button, or use F5, or just go to Debug > Start Debugging.

Comment: I need to debug from IIS process.