# Why is my app not using scaffolded Identity pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, scaffolding

I have an app where I wish to focus on some Identity function enhancements, e.g. password generation etc. I have used "Add scaffolded item->Identity", and each Identity page seems complete and fine.

Yet when I put breakpoints e.g. in the ctor of `Login.cshtml.cs`, they are not hit, as if the compiled Identity pages are still running the show.

What have I missed in scaffolding out the pages?

Comment: Have you use authentication middleware ? ie :  app.UseAuthentication(); inside configure method of startup ?

Comment: @DiwasPoudel Yes, I have `app.UseAuthentication();`, but the authentication does work anyway, just not using the scaffolded pages, like it's still using the Identity library code.

Comment: @ProfK Can you post your `Startup` class

Comment: try to run `Update-Package` in `Package Manager Console`

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the followings:

- Make sure that VS not switched to *Release* mode (instead of *Debug*
  mode)
- If possible, run your VS as the admin, check it. Maybe you could try
  to change the platform target(Any CPU, X86, X64).
- To make sure that the symbols are loaded for your app, I think you
  would get more information from the Output window, see [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimgries/archive/2007/08/07/visual-studio-debugger-faq.aspx) and [PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know](https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know/) .
- Make sure that it has the same framework version when you use the
  attach process, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181401/vs-2008-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-th/13106908#13106908).

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thanks a lot :)